# Elixir iex suspends process for inactivity after a minute

Tags: shell, elixir

Couldn't find anything on google describing this issue for either Elixir or Erlang. I am seeing the iex shell suspend itself after a minute of inactivity.

Is this an intended feature or something possibly with my shell? I've tried using several different shells (bash, csh, zsh, sh) and they all do the same thing.

Its just a bit of annoyance really. I'm trying to learn elixir and so I will have some documentation or examples in my browser with iex in a terminal open at the same time. Every time I go back to the terminal, the process is suspended.

Heres some sample terminal output:

```
➜ iex
Erlang R16B02 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-    poll:false] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (0.12.5) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>
        [1]  + 24986 suspended  iex
                                   %
```

If iex is doing this intentionally, is this configurable to turn it off?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you suspended `iex` using `CTRL+Z` or something like it. You can usually just use `fg` to get back to the suspended task. Coincidentally, I've had an `iex` shell running for the last 4 days straight, and haven't seen this. Perhaps if you provided more info about your environment or platform, we might be able to better pin down exactly what's happening here.

Comment: I know that this looks like I hit CTRL+Z, but I didn't. It happens automatically. I'm on OSX Mavericks, using oh-my-zsh with iTerm. An interesting thing though that I just discovered, the Terminal application doesn't seem to have this problem... Why would iTerm do that?

Comment: Interesting, I'm also on 10.9, and using iTerm, though I'm using fish rather than zsh. My version of iTerm is Build 1.0.0.20140112, could you post what version you have? I went through all the settings I could, but I don't see anything that would trigger this behavior, unless you have some hotkeys configured in iTerm that trigger `CTRL+Z`. You could also try enabling debug logging, and looking to see what happens when it suspends `iex`.

Comment: My version is exactly identical, 1.0.0.20140112. It typically happens while I'm not looking at the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out... iTerm2 has an option under Preferences, Profiles -> Session (tab) -> When idle, send ASCII code: [ 0 ].

Turning this off makes it stop doing this, not sure why iex responds this way.